# How can I resize an image of size [2, 1024, 20, 1] to [2, 1024, 9, 1] in PyTorch?

Tags: image, pytorch

I'm working with PyTorch and I have image data with dimensions [2, 1024, 20, 1]. I want to resize it to [2, 1024, 9, 1]. None of the methods I've tried seem to work.

If you know of any simple approaches or code snippets to accomplish this task, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share them!

Here are my tries...

```py
class ImageResize0(nn.Module):
    """
    Image Down Sampling
    from (batch, channel, 20, 1) to (batch, channel, 9, 1)
    """

    def __init__(self, scale_factor):
        super(ImageResize0, self).__init__()
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.interpolate(x, scale_factor=self.scale_factor, mode="nearest")
        return x
```

or

```py
class ImageResize1(nn.Module):
    """
    Image Down Sampling
    from (batch, 1024, 20, 1) to (batch, 1024, 9, 1)
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(ImageResize1, self).__init__()
        self.conv_0 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=729, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.linear_0 = nn.Linear(in_features=729, out_features=9)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch, channel, height, width = x.size()
        x = self.conv_0(x)
        x = x.view(batch, -1)
        x = self.linear_0(x)
        x = x.view(batch, channel, 9, 1)
```